# Why is resistance $U/I$ rather than $I/U$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

What is the difference between resistance and conductance and why is resistance $U/I$ and not $I/U$? (I know $I/U$ is conductance.) But I don't *see* the difference between both.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate? Seeing that you do know that one is the inverse of the other you do know there is a difference

Comment: Hi Bort, Yes I know there's a mathematical difference, but I don't really understand the difference or the meaning of I/U and U/I.

Comment: $U/I$ is called resistance, $I/U$ is called *conductivity*.  The former states how much voltage is needed for a currant, the later how much currant will be induced by a given voltage. Not much of a difference, really.

Comment: Maybe the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy is helpful to your understanding of either one of these quantities

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because if the definitions of conductance and resistance were switched, the behavior of those variables would run counter to the common meaning of the names of the variables.

Since $V = I R$, for a given voltage, the greater the resistance, the **lower** the current - this means the charges are flowing more slowly. That matches the English meaning of the word "resistance" - the ability to oppose or prevent something from happening.

Conductance is the inverse; $V = I / G$, thus for a given voltage, the greater the conductance, the **higher** the current. This matches the meaning of the english root "conduct", which means to lead, or guide, or transmit something.